# Binary Minimum Spanning Tree (from complete graph)

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Given a weighted complete graph (or more exactly, a matrix of pairwise metric distances between vertices), I need to find a good approximation of the **binary** spanning tree of lowest total cost.

There are a lot of good methods to find the MST, and a few heuristics to find a degree-constrained MST. But the latter are for any degree and pretty heavy to implement and run.

*Is there might be some good heuristics for the special case where the degree is 2 **and** the graph is complete…*

(I'm more concerned with easiness of implementation/speed than optimality)

Bonus question: my goal is actually to get a *radius*-constrained MST (in the hope of solving the [apparently too complex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454492/extract-the-overall-structure-backbone-of-a-set-of-vertices) task of finding a graph/tree's "backbone")… A binary MST seems like it would give me a good approximation (or at least a warm start for local optimisation). Does my intuition make sense?